# Counting the Frequency a Value appears in a given "set" within a DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
 Department    ID     Sale
    1          Jim       1
    1          Sue       1
    1          John      1
    2          Bob       0
    2          Janet     0
    2          Jim       0
    3          John      1
    3          John      1
    3          Jim       1
```

**What I am trying to do**
I want to count the number of departments where a given name appears that has made a sale within that department.  This is somewhat confusing so it is better illustrated with my expected output:

```
  ID       #ofDepartments
  Jim            2
  Sue            1
  John           2
  Bob            0
  Janet          0
```

Notice that John and Jim both have a two next to their names because they both made sales within two different departments (even though John made two sales in dept 3 and one in dept 1, he only appears in two departments overall whereas Jim appeared in three departments but only made sales in two).

I am completely racking my brain how to achieve this as I have tried every possible permutation of groupby without success.  Any help?

Edit:  the closest I've come was using something like

```
  df.groupby(['ID']).sum()
```

but that "double counts" the sales John made in department three so it makes it seem as though he has sold in three departments instead of just two

Comment: Do you want those `0` values as well?

Comment: Yes, Bob and Janet need to have zeroes

Comment: Yes, it is a binary variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before grouping, to drop duplicates based on `Department` and `ID` . Then group based on `ID` and then take `sum()`. Example -

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Department','ID']).groupby('ID')['Sale'].sum()
```

Demo -

```
In [68]: df
Out[68]:
   Department     ID  Sale
0           1    Jim     1
1           1    Sue     1
2           1   John     1
3           2    Bob     0
4           2  Janet     0
5           3   John     1
6           3   John     1
7           3    Jim     1
8           3  Peggy     1

In [69]: df.drop_duplicates(['Department','ID']).groupby('ID')['Sale'].sum()
Out[69]:
ID
Bob      0
Janet    0
Jim      2
John     2
Peggy    1
Sue      1
Name: Sale, dtype: int64
```